# Filter image from lookup image with Core Image

Tags: ios, swift, core-image

I'm trying to develop some color filters for images in my app. We use lookup images as they are easy to use to copy filters from other programs, and convenient to get the same results across platforms. Our lookups look like this

[image]

Previously, we've used `GPUImage` for filtering with lookup images, but I'd like to avoid this dependency as it's a whopping 5.4mb and we only need this one feature.

After searching for a couple of hours, I can't seem to find any resources as to how I can use a lookup image to filter an image trough `CoreImage`. However, looking at the docs, [`CIColorMatrix`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIColorMatrix) looks like the proper tool. The catch here is that I'm way too dumb to understand how this works. Which brings me to my question;

**Does anyone have an example of how to use `CIColorMatrix` to filter an image from lookups?** (or any pointers as to how I should proceed to figure it out myself)

I've scraped trough `GPUImage`s code, and it looks like the shaders they use to filter from lookup images are defined as follows:

Lookup image shader:

```
varying vec2 textureCoordinate;
varying vec2 textureCoordinate2; 
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture; 
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture2;

 // lookup texture  uniform float intensity;  
 void main() {     
    vec4 textureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate); 
    float blueColor = textureColor.b * 63.0; 

    vec2 quad1;    
    quad1.y = floor(floor(blueColor) / 8.0);
    quad1.x = floor(blueColor) - (quad1.y * 8.0);

    vec2 quad2;
    quad2.y = floor(ceil(blueColor) / 8.0);
    quad2.x = ceil(blueColor) - (quad2.y * 8.0);

    vec2 texPos1;   
    texPos1.x = (quad1.x * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.r);
    texPos1.y = (quad1.y * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.g); 

    vec2 texPos2;     
    texPos2.x = (quad2.x * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.r);
    texPos2.y = (quad2.y * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.g);          

    vec4 newColor1 = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, texPos1);   
    vec4 newColor2 = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, texPos2); 
    vec4 newColor = mix(newColor1, newColor2, fract(blueColor));   

    gl_FragColor = mix(textureColor, vec4(newColor.rgb, textureColor.w), intensity);
}
```

In addition to this vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate; 
attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate2;
varying vec2 textureCoordinate;
varying vec2 textureCoordinate2;

void main() {
    gl_Position = position;   
    textureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy;     
    textureCoordinate2 = inputTextureCoordinate2.xy;
}
```

Can/should I rather create my own filter using these shaders?

Comment: GPUImage is under BSD-3 Clause license. You can just get needed part of library and use in your project.

Comment: @IvanSmetanin Good point! I tried looking trough the code (updated question), but as huge libraries go, it's pretty intertwined and hard to grab just a few parts out from it. I'd also prefer to avoid their somewhat proprietary syntax, as I'm a big fan of going vanilla and trusting  library design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**All credit for this answer goes to Nghia Tran. If you see this, thank you!**

Turns out, there was one single answer out there all along. Nghia Tran wrote an article [here](https://nghiatran.me/filter-me-color-lookup-table-part-2/) where he solves my exact use case.

He kindly provided an extension to generate a `CIFilter` from a lookup image, which I will paste below to preserve this answer for future developers.

You'll need to import `CIFilter+LUT.h` in your bridging header if you're using Swift.

Here's a snippet that demonstrates using it on the GPU in **Swift 4**. This is far from optimized, the context etc should be cached, but its a good starting point.

```
static func applyFilter(with lookupImage: UIImage, to image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
    guard let cgInputImage = image.cgImage else {
        return nil
    }

    guard let glContext = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES2) else {
        return nil
    }

    let ciContext = CIContext(eaglContext: glContext)

    guard let lookupFilter = CIFilter(lookupImage: lookupImage, dimension: 64) else {
        return nil
    }

    lookupFilter.setValue(CIImage(cgImage: cgInputImage),
                          forKey: "inputImage")

    guard let output = lookupFilter.outputImage else {
        return nil
    }

    guard let cgOutputImage = ciContext.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent) else {
        return nil
    }

    return UIImage(cgImage: cgOutputImage)
}
```

**CIFilter+LUT.h**

```
#import <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>
@import UIKit.UIImage;

@class CIFilter;

@interface CIFilter (LUT)
+(CIFilter *) filterWithLookupImage:(UIImage *)image dimension:(NSInteger) n;
@end
```

**CIFilter+LUT.m**

```
#import "CIFilter+LUT.h"
#import <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>
#import <OpenGLES/EAGL.h>

@implementation CIFilter (LUT)

+(CIFilter *)filterWithLookupImage:(UIImage *)image dimension:(NSInteger)n {
    NSInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(image.CGImage);
    NSInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(image.CGImage);
    NSInteger rowNum = height / n;
    NSInteger columnNum = width / n;

    if ((width % n != 0) || (height % n != 0) || (rowNum * columnNum != n)) {
        NSLog(@"Invalid colorLUT");
        return nil;
    }

    unsigned char *bitmap = [self createRGBABitmapFromImage:image.CGImage];

    if (bitmap == NULL) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSInteger size = n * n * n * sizeof(float) * 4;
    float *data = malloc(size);
    int bitmapOffest = 0;
    int z = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row <  rowNum; row++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < n; y++) {
            int tmp = z;
            for (int col = 0; col < columnNum; col++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
                    float r = (unsigned int)bitmap[bitmapOffest];
                    float g = (unsigned int)bitmap[bitmapOffest + 1];
                    float b = (unsigned int)bitmap[bitmapOffest + 2];
                    float a = (unsigned int)bitmap[bitmapOffest + 3];

                    NSInteger dataOffset = (z*n*n + y*n + x) * 4;

                    data[dataOffset] = r / 255.0;
                    data[dataOffset + 1] = g / 255.0;
                    data[dataOffset + 2] = b / 255.0;
                    data[dataOffset + 3] = a / 255.0;

                    bitmapOffest += 4;
                }
                z++;
            }
            z = tmp;
        }
        z += columnNum;
    }

    free(bitmap);

    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorCube"];
    [filter setValue:[NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:data length:size freeWhenDone:YES] forKey:@"inputCubeData"];
    [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:n] forKey:@"inputCubeDimension"];

    return filter;
}

+ (unsigned char *)createRGBABitmapFromImage:(CGImageRef)image {
    CGContextRef context = NULL;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    unsigned char *bitmap;
    NSInteger bitmapSize;
    NSInteger bytesPerRow;

    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(image);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(image);

    bytesPerRow = (width * 4);
    bitmapSize = (bytesPerRow * height);

    bitmap = malloc(bitmapSize);
    if (bitmap == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    if (colorSpace == NULL) {
        free(bitmap);
        return NULL;
    }

    context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmap, width,  height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    if (context == NULL) {
        free (bitmap);
    }

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), image);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    return bitmap;
}
@end
```